# How do I fetch only records created in the past year from a table within SSIS package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a column **CT_DT** in a  table. I have to process only transactions created within the past `365 days`.

For example, suppose the current date is **Nov 7, 2012**, I have to process only those transaction that were created since **Nov 7, 2011**. I am using conditional filter within the SSIS package.

Comment: There is no reason to load every record into the buffer and then filter if CT_DT is the transaction date. This will cause the database to return more data than is required, unnecessary memory usage, and a slower processing time. See Siva's first option on filtering out older transactions in the source query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the data in the query you might be using on the data source within the data flow task.

#### Query to filter the data on the source:

```
SELECT  column1
    ,   column2
    ,   column3
FROM    dbo.MyTable
WHERE   DATEDIFF(YEAR, CT_DT, GETDATE()) <= 1
```

If you absolutely want to filter the data on the `Conditional Split` transformation within the Data Flow task, create a new output and set it to the following expression:

#### Expression for Conditional Split:

```
DATEDIFF("yy", CT_DT, GETDATE()) <= 1
```

Your conditional split will look something like this.

[image: Conditional split]

Comment: In my case CT_DT is contain current date and older date too...I tried your logic but it won't work here..I update some of my date 2011/12/31 and this logic filters my this date too....